# How to add a URL attribute in MapRoutes in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following in a .NET Framework MVC VB Project within the RouteConfig in startup:

```
    routes.MapRoute(name:="RaceCardHome", url:="race-card", defaults:=New With {.controller = "Races", .action = "Index"})
    routes.MapRoute(name:="RaceCard", url:="race-card/{raceName}", defaults:=New With {.controller = "Races", .action = "Race"})
```

As you can see the there is a 'url' attribute to change the url so it's not just the {controller}.

How do I accomplish this on .NET Core 2.2 MVC as there doesn't seem to be a URL attribute like above.

```
  app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");

            routes.MapRoute(
               name: "RaceCardHome",
               template: "{controller=Races}/{action=Index}");

            routes.MapRoute(
              name: "RaceCard",
              template: "{controller=Races}/{action=Race}");

        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but this should work.

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
       name: "RaceCardHome",
       template: "race-card",
       defaults: new {controller = "Races", action = "Index"});

    routes.MapRoute(
      name: "RaceCard",
      template: "race-card/{raceName}",
      defaults: new {controller = "Races", action = "Race"});

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
});
```

Also, a point to note is the route named `"default"` should always be at the end.

More details can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#create-routes)

Comment: I did this before and it didn't work. Now I have moved the 'default' map route to the bottom it has worked. Thanks.

Comment: Great, please accept the answer using the tick to help others coming here.